# Custom error page not getting called

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement my own custom error page in MVC 4. Basically when users try to view `Details` of any product with non-existent productID, I want this custom error page.

I created my own custom error page  `NotFound.aspx`

The inside content of this page is :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Simple.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo>" %> 
<asp:Content ID="errorTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"> 
Error 
</asp:Content> 
<asp:Content ID="errorContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
<h2> 
Sorry, you requested a product that doesn't exist. Make sure you
requested a valid ProductID 
</h2> 
</asp:Content>
```

And then Applied the `HandleError` filter to my ActionMethod: `Details` as:

```
[HandleError(View="NotFound")] 
public ActionResult Details(int id) {...
```

The problem is that, Always the default view :  `Views/Shared/Error.aspx` is being called and not the new custom error page. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that my `ProductController` class also needs to have  the `order` property set as:

```
[HandleError(Order=2)] 
public class ProductController : Controller { ... }
```

*What this means*: An Order value of 2 will ensure that the controller-wide filter will be applied only if there isn’t a 
HandleError filter with a higher order available.

And this worked perfectly. My web.config setting are:
`<customErrors mode="On" />` .

This is it. The `defaultRedirect` is not needed at all.

**NOTE:**
I had the `HandleError` filter initially with NO  `order` property.

```
[HandleError] 
public class ProductController : Controller { ... }
```

When you apply the HandleError filter with no arguments, you are specifying that any exception 
thrown by the methods covered by the filter will result in the `Views/Shared/Error.aspx` view being used.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (but i am not sure about working of this code in MVC). Paste this code in configuration section in web.config file brlow system.web.

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Comment: CustomErrors mode was already ON. Else if it would have been off then even the default error page would not show up. Any other ideas ???

Comment: Actually i have no idea about the MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Try using custom errors tag found in the web config file that might help you.

Here is the sample

```
<system.web>
   <--- other required may be used here--->     

    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Didn't worked. Even If i remove the default redirect attribute, it takes me to my defaultview of error. so definitely i guess it has got no role to play here.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your "notfound" action and "detail" action in the same controller. Otherwise, you should specifiy the controller name, or put the notfound.aspx under the shared folder

Comment: It is under shared folder only. And notfound is Not an Action, just a view.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it before!  Did you throw an Http 404 from the action method ? Actually, if the expcetion is not an http 500,the HandleError will ignore it. Maybe this is the reason why always show the default view.